# Function pointers in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I suppose in some ways either (or both) `Delegate` or `MethodInfo` qualify for this title. However, neither provide the syntactic niceness that I'm looking for. So, in short, Is there some way that I can write the following:

```
FunctionPointer foo = // whatever, create the function pointer using mechanisms
foo();
```

I can't use a solid delegate (ie, using the `delegate` keyword to declare a delegate type) because there is no way of knowing till runtime the exact parameter list. For reference, here's what I've been toying with in LINQPad currently, where `B` will be (mostly) user generated code, and so will `Main`, and hence for nicety to my users, I'm trying to remove the `.Call`:

```
void Main()
{
    A foo = new B();
    foo["SomeFuntion"].Call();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
interface IFunction {
    void Call();
    void Call(params object[] parameters);
}

class A {
    private class Function : IFunction {
        private MethodInfo _mi;
        private A _this;
        public Function(A @this, MethodInfo mi) {
            _mi = mi;
            _this = @this;
        }

        public void Call() { Call(null); }
        public void Call(params object[] parameters) {
            _mi.Invoke(_this, parameters);
        }
    }

    Dictionary<string, MethodInfo> functions = new Dictionary<string, MethodInfo>();

    public A() {
        List<MethodInfo> ml = new List<MethodInfo>(this.GetType().GetMethods());
        foreach (MethodInfo mi in typeof(Object).GetMethods())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ml.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ml[i].Name == mi.Name)
                    ml.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        foreach (MethodInfo mi in ml)
        {
            functions[mi.Name] = mi;
        }
    }

    public IFunction this[string function] {
        get { 
            if (!functions.ContainsKey(function))
                throw new ArgumentException();

            return new Function(this, functions[function]);
        }
    }
}

sealed class B : A {
    public void SomeFuntion() {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeFunction called.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You say you want to keep the number and type of parameters open, but you can do that with a delgate:

```
public delegate object DynamicFunc(params object[] parameters);
```

This is exactly the same thing you currently have. Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DynamicFunc f = par =>
                        {
                            foreach (var p in par)
                                Console.WriteLine(p);

                            return null;
                        };

        f(1, 4, "Hi");
    }
}
```

You can think of an instance-method delegate as very similar to your `Function` class: an object an a `MethodInfo`. So there's no need to rewrite it.

Also function pointers in C and C++ are not any closer to what you need: they cannot be bound to an object instance *and* function, and also they are statically typed, not dynamically typed.

If you want to "wrap" any other method in a DynamicFunc delegate, try this:

```
public static DynamicFunc MakeDynamicFunc(object target, MethodInfo method)
{
    return par => method.Invoke(target, par);
}

public static void Foo(string s, int n)    
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

and then:

```
DynamicFunc f2 = MakeDynamicFunc(null, typeof(Program).GetMethod("Foo"));

f2("test", 100);
```

Note that I'm using a static method `Foo` so I pass `null` for the instance, but if it was an instance method, I'd be passing the object to bind to. `Program` happens to be the class my static methods are defined in.

Of course, if you pass the wrong argument types then you get errors at runtime. I'd probably look for a way to design your program so that as much type information is captured at compile time as possible.

Comment: While I consider you a genius for thinking of this, I'm getting bind errors when I try to create the delegate with: return (DynamicFunction)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(DynamicFunction),
    this, functions[function]);

Comment: That's a lot more complex... hang on.

Comment: Compile time for the `B` class will be runtime, as I said, it's user-generated, so sadly, any errors there will have to handled by them (and there are good provisions, error reporting, etc, to do that).

Comment: Fair enough - to paraphrase Einstein, a program should be as statically-typed as possible, but no statically-typed-er.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another bit of code you could use; Reflection is rather slow, so if you expect your Dynamic function calls to be called frequently, you don't want method.Invoke inside the delegate:

```
public delegate void DynamicAction(params object[] parameters);
static class DynamicActionBuilder
{
    public static void PerformAction0(Action a, object[] pars) { a(); }
    public static void PerformAction1<T1>(Action<T1> a, object[] p) {
        a((T1)p[0]);
    }
    public static void PerformAction2<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> a, object[] p) {
        a((T1)p[0], (T2)p[1]);
    }
    //etc...

    public static DynamicAction MakeAction(object target, MethodInfo mi) {
        Type[] typeArgs =
            mi.GetParameters().Select(pi => pi.ParameterType).ToArray();
        string perfActName = "PerformAction" + typeArgs.Length;
        MethodInfo performAction =
            typeof(DynamicActionBuilder).GetMethod(perfActName);
        if (typeArgs.Length != 0)
            performAction = performAction.MakeGenericMethod(typeArgs);
        Type actionType = performAction.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
        Delegate action = Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, target, mi);
        return (DynamicAction)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            typeof(DynamicAction), action, performAction);
    }
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
static class TestDab
{
    public static void PrintTwo(int a, int b) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", a, b);
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", a, b));//for immediate window.
    }
    public static void PrintHelloWorld() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Trace.WriteLine("Hello World!");//for immediate window.
    }

    public static void TestIt() {
        var dynFunc = DynamicActionBuilder.MakeAction(null,
            typeof(TestDab).GetMethod("PrintTwo"));
        dynFunc(3, 4);
        var dynFunc2 = DynamicActionBuilder.MakeAction(null,
            typeof(TestDab).GetMethod("PrintHelloWorld"));
        dynFunc2("extraneous","params","allowed"); //you may want to check this.
    }
}
```

This will be quite a bit faster; each dynamic call will involve 1 typecheck per param, 2 delegate calls, and one array construction due to the params-style passing.

Comment: I do seem to recall something about Invoke being slow and to use CreateDelegate instead, which is why I jumped on that solution to start with, since it's entirely possible these functions will be called a great many times per second... I'll look over the details of this when I'm not half asleep however (reads: 8 hours or so)

Comment: Out of curiosity I timed this technique (with two parameters) against mine, and found that my method has an overhead of three and half **millionths of a second** per call. So I suspect the overhead is unlikely to be an issue in a real application; depends what kind of things your users will be doing in their functions.